# Android Receivers not doing as expected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

Well honestly, they aren't doing anything at all. Let me start by saying that I know that Android reworked receivers in 3.1, specifically boot control. I know that they made it so that ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED cannot be used unless the application has been previously launched by the user. However, people have been successful in using them in current application, yet I am never hitting my receivers for my BOOT_COMPLETED or my SHUTDOWN.

Quick Edit - Please look at the bottom of this post for corrected Shutdown Receiver, I have gotten it to work and am now just stuck in my efforts to get BOOT_COMPLETED to work.

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smashingboxes.speedblock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

...

```
    <!-- RECEIVERS -->
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHUTDOWN" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Now my implemented receiver classes are fairly straight forward:

BOOT_COMPLETED Receiver (the one that isn't working)

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        Intent starterIntent = new Intent(c, LaunchActivity.class);

        // Start the activity (by utilizing the passed context)
        starterIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        c.getApplicationContext().startService(starterIntent);  
    }
}
```

I have tried different things based on what I have seen as far as solutions, such as altering my launching activity to include

```
/* May need this, as of 3.1 we can't call BOOT_COMPLETED until the app has been run successfully */
Intent intent = new Intent("com.smashingboxes.speedblock.intent");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

or including this in my boot receiver intent-filter in my manifest

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Nothing seems to work. When Logs are inserted into my receiver methods they are never hit. Apparently people are still using these two receivers fairly regularly, which is why I am having trouble understanding why neither of them work. Have I missed something with my registration or something?

--EDIT--

I have solved the problem with my shutdown receiver. First, I foolishly forgot the ACTION_ portion of the tag. Secondly, HTC has separate shutdown methods, in my case I needed to add an intent-filter to my Receiver request:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Now my Shutdown Receiver works, still no luck on the Boot Completed Receiver though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I think that it is actually important to note, as it seems like an issue others will run into at some point. My issue was that I was launching a "Launcher Activity" called just that, LauncherActivity. Basically, it acted as my gateway to start up services, receivers, and such when the application was launched. It is a very simple Activity class:

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* May need this, as of 3.1 we can't call BOOT_COMPLETED until the app has been run successfully */
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.smashingboxes.speedapp.intent");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

    // NOTE: It is VERY, VERY important that we DO NOT finish this activity.
    // If we do, our BootReceiver will no longer receive its broadcast and 
    // we won't auto-start on boot
    //finish();
}
```

}

Note that I was calling finish() on the LaunchActivity. The problem with this is that it seemed to tell Android that the application was in the stopped state, meaning that it won't allow the reception of the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, even though I had a number of services running in the background. The LauncherActivity MUST stay active throughout the entire life-cycle or the BOOT_COMPLETED receiver becomes useless. Something that I haven't really seen mentioned before, but again something I think is worth noting.